# Know last X field value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with this table

```
+------+---------------------+-------------+
| id   | key                 |    value    |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
|  152 | incidencia_0_fecha  |  20150306   |
|  158 | incidencia_1_fecha  |  20150307   | 
|  234 | incidencia_2_fecha  |  20150309   |
|  .   | ......              |  ........   |
|  n   | incidencia_N_fecha  |  date_value |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
```

And I want to know what is the last key (N its dinamic and i don't know his last value). In this table the last must be `incidencia_2_fecha`.

How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: what is your criteria to call record LAST? max ID? max N in key name? biggest value (date)?

Comment: I presume that your last key has the most recent date (`value` column). Am I right?

Comment: The last record must be the max N in key name. Thanks

Comment: I think this will help: `SELECT key ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( key, '_', 2 ), '_', -1 ) DESC`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the number in the string using two REPLACES.

```
SELECT MAX(
         REPLACE(REPLACE(`key`, 'incidencia_', ''), '_fecha', '')
       )
  FROM mytable
```

Comment: Jordi, no se si puedo escribir en castellano. Pero al ver tu nombre probare. No entiendo el codigo. Esto me dara el ultimo "incidencia"? Gracias

Comment: Esto te dará el número (N) de la última incidencia. Para la última incidencia hay otras queries que puedes usar como por ejemplo: 

     SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY `key` DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the id column are strictly increasing, you can do this:

```
SELECT key FROM your_table WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table);
```

EDIT 1:
If the table is quite large, you should make sure that there's an index on the id column. Otherwise the query could take a long time to run.

EDIT 2:
Another option, if the value column contains the date at the time the record was inserted (and is indexed), would be to do the above query, but replace id with value, i.e.

```
SELECT key FROM your_table WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM your_table);
```

Comment: The last record must be the max N in key name. I can't use id. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First fetch record in desc

SELECT key from tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1